# SVG not resizing Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have an SVG created dynamically which is not being resized correctly in IE11.

All other modes, IE8-IE10 work fine. All other browsers work fine (when I use a special additional CSS). It's just IE11 Edge/IE11 mode that is broken.

Here is the svg I'm using - I've omitted all additional scripts and CSS, and as you can see, it doesn't fill the whole width of the container when running in IE11 Edge mode:

http://jsfiddle.net/37qtg133/

in brief, my layout is:

```
<div style="min-height: 400px">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="left: -0.57px; top: -0.01px; width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; position: relative;" viewBox="0 0 677 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        //svg content
     </svg>
</div>
```

Has anybody been able to solve this problem?
I'm using Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17420IS Update Versions 11.0.14

P.S. Extremely disappointed that IE continues to throw up random problems like this when it was looking like it was just starting to become a good browser

Comment: As a way to make the SVG larger, you can set a min-height in CSS. However this is far from ideal - I may as well make the SVG a set size :/. You can target just IE11 using `_:-ms-fullscreen, :root svg { min-height:200px; }`

Comment: After trying to solve what should be a simple fix with overflow:hidden and finding no actual solutions for 2 hours I can confidently say IE is and never was a good browser.